# avoid the same value appear on different days

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, flickr

What's the logic behind those wallpaper tab chrome extension, where everyday it displays you a wallpaper.

How to ensure wallpaper A for example which already appear before never come back? says I will be using API of flickr.

Answer (score 0):

They could possibly just be getting images at random from a huge collection, where the chances the image will come up again is very low.

Otherwise they could be logging the id's of images which have been used and then cross-reference that list with the collection to make sure that one of those images aren't used again.

Comment: I thought of this, but what if I've limited set of photos? I also thought of storing the img url into localstorage to avoid duplication.

Comment: Try storing the img url into localstorage and then when you select a new img, get the next one (or random one) and then check to see if it's in localstorage before displaying it